# concatenation is not working as expected in perl

Tags: perl

Here is a simple piece of code in perl. Here I can print the value of the key, however I am never able to concatenate $key with $value. Whenever I try to do it the value of $key is not concatenated.Only the $value part gets printed.Can someone please help. This doesnt work with join either.

```
while(my ($key, $value) = each(%symbol_map)) {
  print $key."\n";
  print $key.$value."\n";
  print $DATA_OUT $key." ".$value . "\n";
}
```

Comment: What is it currently printing? What do you expect it to print?

Comment: Here is an example: "134173 HB1 HKFD HKFE 130 830 HKFD" here the value of $key is 134173 and the rest is $value "HB1 HKFD HKFE 130 830 HKFD" on concatenation it prints "HB1 HKFD HKFE 130 830 HKFD" only. Thanks!

Comment: What is output of `keys %symbol_map; use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%symbol_map;`

Comment: Sounds like the $key contains `\r` at the end.

Comment: @deb What is the `version` of the `Perl` you are using

Comment: $VAR1 = {
' => 'HB1 HKFD HKFE 130 830 HKFD',
' => 'MHI HKFD HKFE 130 915 HKFD',
' => 'HB3 HKFD HKFE 130 830 HKFD',
' => 'MCHC HKFD HKFE 130 915 HKFD',
' => 'MHI HKFD HKFE 130 915 HKFD',
' => 'MHI HKFD HKFE 130 915 HKFD',
' => 'HSI HKFD HKFE 130 915 HKFD',
' => 'MHI HKFD HKFE 130 915 HKFD',
' => 'MHI HKFD HKFE 130 915 HKFD',
' => 'EF3 HKFD HKFE 130 830 HKFD',
' => 'DHH HKFD HKFE 130 915 HKFD',
' => 'MHI HKFD HKFE 130 915 HKFD',
' => 'EF3 HKFD HKFE 130 830 HKFD',
' => 'HB3 HKFD HKFE 130 830 HKFD'};

Comment: Here is the perl version:  perl -v

This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Copyright 1987-2009, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

Comment: What is the original value of %symbol_map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your hash is properly defined?

Try inserting `%ENV` instead of `%symbol_map` to see if it will then list your environment correctly. It does so for me.

I am guessing that your symbol table contains:

```
("" =>  "HB1 HKFD HKFE 130 830 HKFD")
```

instead of:

```
("134173" =>  "HB1 HKFD HKFE 130 830 HKFD")
```